# how do I create a program that takes random tuples from a list of tuples and generates a basic plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples

I want to create a program which randomly takes a tuple from a list of tuples and plot them as a line plot. if I had a list of tuples `dataP = [(1,3), (5,4), (2,2)]` I would want it to generate a line plot, taking [0] as the x-axis and [1] as the y-axis.

in fact I have succeeded in plotting. I've tried this code:

```
dataP = [(1,3)]
x_val = [x[0] for x in dataP]
y_val = [x[1] for x in dataP]

print(x_val)
plt.plot(x_val,y_val)
plt.plot(x_val,y_val,'or')
plt.show()
```

and I got this:
[basic plot using tuples, jupyter notebook][1]

I also tried to make a line plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =  [(0, 3), (1,2),
 (2, 5), (3,1),
 (4, 4), (5, 0)]

x_val = [x[0] for x in data]
y_val = [x[1] for x in data]

print(x_val)
plt.plot(x_val,y_val)
plt.plot(x_val,y_val,'or')
plt.show()
```

a satisfying result:
[line plot of tuples, jupyter notebook][2]

what I am unable to do is write a program which takes a random tuple from the list and plots a point (which in this case is a dot) on the graph.

how do I do it? thank you.

Comment: Do you have a predefined list which has tuples in it? Or you want to generate tuples also randomly?

Comment: @SrivatsavRaghu yes. I'll have a predefined list and a program that picks a random tuple and plots it.

Comment: Okay then you already have a person answering your query.

Answer (score 0):

`random` package has `sample` and `choice` methods

`choice` returns a random value from a list
`sample` returns `k` random values from a list

Here's an example

```
import random

data = [(0, 3), (1, 2),
        (2, 5), (3, 1),
        (4, 4), (5, 0)]

print(random.choice(data))
print(random.sample(data, 2))
```

Here's my output

```
(3, 1)
[(5, 0), (2, 5)]
```

Here's your code that shows 3 random points and 1 random point respectively

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [(0, 3), (1, 2),
        (2, 5), (3, 1),
        (4, 4), (5, 0)]

# multiple points
random_points = random.sample(data, 3)

x_val = [i[0] for i in random_points]
y_val = [i[1] for i in random_points]

plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
plt.plot(x_val, y_val, 'or')
plt.show()

# single point
single_random_point = random.choice(data)
plt.plot(*single_random_point, 'or')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried to do what you said but I got an error: "Value error: 'a' must be 1-dimensional".

Comment: I edited my answer with a working example. Hope it works this time